# Is it necessary to use the indefinite article before the words "mother", "mom", "dad", "father" when saying that someone has one?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Is necessary to use the indefinite article before *mom*, *mother*, *dad*, *father* when saying that someone has one? For example:

> Do you have **a** mom?
>
> Do you have Mom?

Comment: Yes, because Mom/Mum/Mother is the speaker's _own_ mother.

Comment: Also `your`, sometimes.  "Here is your report card, Allen.   Go show it to Mom."

Answer (score 1):

In this context when mom, mother etc. are used as nouns it's neccesarry to use a/an.

When you use mom, mother etc. as proper nouns, you can often omit the a/an, like in the sentence below.

> This is for Mom.

Take a look here for more information, [When to use a an or the](https://www.gallaudet.edu/tutorial-and-instructional-programs/english-center/grammar-and-vocabulary/when-to-use-a-an-or-the).

Comment: But we do say "Please give this to mum"  (and not "Please give this to a mum" or Please give this to the mum")  It is clear that "mum" is sometimes used without an article.

Comment: One way to think of this use: you can omit the article if either of the first-person possessives `my` or `our` is implied.  (More rarely also `your`, especially if you are speaking to a child.)

Comment: Notice that "mom" is still used as a noun in "This is for Mom."   But it is used more like a /proper noun/, so it does not require an article.   It is most often capitalized in this use, just as if it were a proper noun or name.

Comment: In the "proper noun" examples, the word "Mom" is not *being used as* a proper noun, it *is* a proper noun (and thus technically needs to be capitalized as well).  "mom" (lower case) is a noun (a general category/type of person), and "Mom" (upper case) is a proper noun (a name used to refer to a specific person).  When the proper noun ("Mom") is used, like any other name, it requires that the speaker and listener have a shared understanding of which person that name applies to (so generally, "Mom" = "my mother", but when talking to a child sometimes "Mom" = "your mother", etc)